# Ошибка Invalid syntax на строке с циклом for

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, pillow

У меня python 3.4 выводит `Invalid syntax` на строку:

```
for i in range(len(face_result)):
```

А вот и сам код:

```
import telebot
from PIL import Image
from random import randint
import requests
import json
token = "хххххххххххххх"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=token)
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start_handler(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Фарту мастер ауе")
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["photo"])
def picture(message):
    im = message.photo[-1].convert('RGBA')
    result = requests.post("https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/emotion/v1.0/recognize", data=content, headers={"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
                                "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "ed949f112a524980ad1907524eb7d32d"})
    face_result = json.loads(result.text)
    im2 = message.photo[-1].convert('RGBA')
    mask = Image.open(random.choose(["mask.png", "mask1.png", "mask2.png"]).convert('RGBA')
    for i in range(len(face_result)):
        rectangle = face_result[i]['faceRectangle']
        x = rectangle['left']
        y = rectangle['top']
        w = rectangle['width']
        h = rectangle['height']
        box = (x, y, x + w, y + h)
        m = im2.resize((w, h))
        im.paste(m, box, m)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, im2)
family.show()
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def polegche(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Полегче, я не делаю мемы из текста.")
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Вы только что скомпрометировали токен, срочно замените его.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот проблемный кусок

```
mask = Image.open(random.choose(["mask.png", "mask1.png", "mask2.png"]).convert('RGBA')
for i in range(len(face_result)):
```

В первой из строк у вас открыто 3 круглых скобки, а закрыто 2. Ругается на вторую строку из-за того, что Python ожидает, что в ней он все-таки найдет недостающую скобку, а в итоге находит двоеточие.